# Properly set up a read only user in MongoDB 3.0?

Tags: mongodb

I have created a user for my database `dbase` with a `read` role with the following command:
`db.createUser({user: "user" , pwd: "password" , roles: [{role: "read", db: "dbase"}] })`

The problem is he can still `insert` and `remove` a document from the collection. How do I properly set up a read only user in MongoDB?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Answer (score 3):

Allright, I found it.

You have to enable client access control by doing the following:

1. Edit the `/etc/mongod.conf` file
2. Add the following lines

`security:
    authorization: enabled`

3. Restart MongoDB:

`sudo service mongodb restart`